# Read JSON file and represent it graphical tree view

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, web-deployment

Hello, I am very new to web development by using React JS and have a doubt below.

How to represent Json object data into graphical view like tree view at UI side by using react js ?? And also need to do two way binding as well, if user do the changes at UI, same should be rendered at original Json object as well.

Comment: Both of these topics can be easily researched. Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. Come back when you have problems with some real code that you can't resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may represent your JSON tree as you want, for example - you can 'draw' your structure with a collections of divs. You can map thru your json-array and represent you UI. Something like:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="entities">
        { 
          this.props.myObjects.map( (obj, index) => 
          { 
            return <Link key={index} to={`/somepath/${index}`} >
            <div><p>{obj.name}</p></div></Link> 
          })
        }
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Parents div may have redbackgrounds, nested divs may have indents and another background color. Your question is not specifically. What are you want to do?

React nature is not supported two way databindings. If your user changes data - you need to save data manually. If you will use Redux as well, this is not a big deal.

Comment: Thank you..
my doubt is..How to represent dynamic JSON object data into graphical tree structure at UI,  since i haven't found any feasible react components. example like react-treeview and react-ui-tree components, i have gone through those components but they are rendering as folder hierarchical manner. But my requirement is to present as flow diagram based on json data which i have received through rest API calls.

Please suggest..Thanks in advance.

Comment: sample flow diagram mentioned in below link..
https://blog.pusher.com/making-reactjs-realtime-with-websockets/

Comment: I have got an answer for this.. and it can done by using goJS component integration in react. Thankful to victor.